# Django send_mail does not work with mailgun

Tags: python, django, django-views, mailgun, django-email

Settings:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.mailgun.org'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'donotreply@kamiltrojnar.pl'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'passwordsecret'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'donotreply@kamiltrojnar.pl'
SITE_ID = 2
```

Output in console:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Subject: Testing email sending 
From: donotreply@kamiltrojnar.pl
To: kamil.trojnar@gmail.com
Date: Tue, 13 Nov 2018 17:20:27 -0000
Message-ID <154212962720.11272.17395367179025062268@DESKTOP-EG7NCN4.home>
```

View:

```
def index(request):
    send_mail("Testing email sending", 'AS  title','donotreply@kamiltrojnar.pl',['kamil.trojnar@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False)

    return render(request, 'userpanel/index.html')
```

I get no errors but the email is not sent. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are using the console email backend, so emails are printed in the console but are not sent:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

To use the SMTP server settings, use the [SMTP backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/email/#smtp-backend):

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

Alternatively, you could use a library that supports mailgun, for example [`django-anymail`](https://github.com/anymail/django-anymail). Then you would add your mailgun API key to your settings instead of SMTP settings, and the backend would use the mailgun API to send the emails.